Force Quarto to follow a specific Style for captions
I have a reference document (.docx) file that I use in my Quarto document. The problem is that for capturing both figures and tables, Quarto uses the style called "Image Caption". I want to have Quarto follow the Style that I specify for figures and tables separately (because I want figure captions to be centralized, but table captions to be left-aligned). Is it possible?
Here is how I create my figures, and tables follow the same format:
#| label: fig-figure2
#| fig-cap: "My caption"
knitr::include_graphics("figures/fig2.png")

